# HTTP server correctness testing

Tags: http, testing, correctness

I've written a simple HTTP server, and I've stumbled upon a few bugs so far that proved difficult to track down. For example, not adding a blank line between headers and content of a response, or giving an incorrect challenge response for a WebSocket connection. With such bugs, it seems Firefox usually ignores them and displays the page anyway, and Chrome just closes the socket without giving any error message.

Is there a simple, free program out there that will place some requests to my server and report every little thing it does wrong, so I can track down these bugs? I've seen a few such programs, but none free, and I don't really want to invest a lot into a hobby project. (Maybe Chrome even has a flag that makes it explain the problem when it closes a socket?)

I'm not as concerned about dealing with weird requests from a client (as Apache Test seems to focus on) - what I need to verify is that sane requests get correct responses that won't confuse the client.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the tests for an existing server and pointing them at yours instead.

Comment: I imagine those would be designed mainly to test that the server works and that old bugs haven't cropped back up, as opposed to a full "acid test" that verifies compliance with HTTP/WebSocket/etc specs?

Comment: You said you wanted simple tests to test sane requests--seems like that's what the request testing portion of a server test suite would have.